# Reduce time machine backup size

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, timemachine

I want to create a testing setup where i just want to take backup of 1gb folder through time machine on nas device.

Even after removing hidden files from time machine backup prefereces, it shows 15-16 gb, is there any clue to reduce it more?

Another issue I am facing is it takes 15-20 mins to prepare it, Is there any way to reduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Using disk utility app I created a new volume of desired size. Excluded other partition and took back up.